# There are 3 students and 10 advisors. How many ways can each student be assigned an advisor if no advisor advises all 3 students?

Tags: combinatorics

If I understand this question correctly, should we break this question up into multiple cases where an advisor can advise two students, and then another advisor can advise another? After that, we add that to the case where each student has a different advisor. Would that mean:

$$(10 * 9 * 8) + (10 *9 *1) $$

We multiply by 1 since one advisor must be repeated.

Comment: Not quite.  For the case in which exactly two students have the same advisor, you must choose which two of the three students are assigned to that advisor.

Answer (score 1):

Count the total number of assignments, then subtract the number of invalid ones. Usually the way to go when counting things.

$$10^3 - 10$$

It's easy to count the number of ways all students can be assigned to the same advisor: it's just 10.